# can't start a django project in windows 7

Tags: django-admin

I'm using django to do my project in ubuntu and am trying to move it into windows but am having a problem. When i issued **django-admin.py startproject mysite** in windows, instead of creating mysite it rather behaves like running just **django-admin.py** command. Infact no subcommand works with **django admin.py**

Comment: Can you provide the exact output/screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Use django-admin startproject mysite to create a project in windows instead of django-admin.py startproject mysite. That means, avoid .py

Answer (score 0):

Windows isn't developer friendly. If you are coming from an Ubuntu background and miss bash then you should use Cygwin. I bash, git, mercurial, python, virtualenv, pip and django working  on cygwin just as good as it works on linux.